# Why can't I use pip with Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have checked that I have python 3.8 installed on my windows10 machine. I'm trying to install a package with pip but the terminal tells me '[pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.]

I understand that Python versions above 3.4 have pip pre-installed, so why am I getting this error message?

[image: This is what I mean]

Comment: Can you cd into the directory where you installed Python, cd into the Scripts folder and try running pip? If you can run pip from there it likely means the pip command is not in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: You must install pip: Download the https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py script and then install it by running `python get-pip.py`

Comment: Try this: install pip by typing the line in terminal or cmd `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` then type `python get-pip.py`. After this do `pip install --upgrade pip` that will solve your problem

Comment: @J.Behnken That was exactly the problem... I added it and everything works fine now

Answer (score 9):

Try accessing pip in the following way:

```
python -m pip --version
```

Comment: This worked and tells me that I have pip v 19.2.3 . But how do I avoid this issue and use pip directly?

Comment: I tried this but i got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Can you install pip this way? `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @ExHunter this is probably because of your python3 version is `3.5.2` but `fstring` is introduced from `python3.6` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html) and hence, it is not identified by your current python version.

Answer (score 2):

You should install pip first.

1. Download `get-pip.py` from [there](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Install via executing `python <path to get-pip.py>` in cmd.

Comment: Here you can read more [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation#pip-install).

Comment: I did come across this article. Doesn't pre-installed mean that I don't have to manually install it?

Comment: @Zaham2, pip is sometimes included automatically when python is installed to your system, and sometimes you have to install it yourself. Also, on windows, sometimes needed to add some paths to PATH environment variable.

Comment: Also this duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I don't believe it does. Mine was just a path issue, that's it